# docker create Linux with my own application

Tags: docker, centos7

I developed an HTTP server which implements RESTful API specified by our client. Currently my workstation (Centos 7.4 x86_64) and everything else is working. Now I need to ship it as Centos 7.4 docker image.

I read the **getting started guide** and spent some time browsing the documentation but am still not sure how to proceed with this.

#### Basic Steps

1. Download Centos image from [here](https://hub.docker.com/_/centos/)
2. Run Centos image on my workstation and copy everything into it.
3. Make an appropriate changes so that server is started via `systemd`.

In step 3 : I am not sure how to do `root/sudo` inside the docker image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you are looking for is the Dockerfile reference https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#understand-how-arg-and-from-interact

It's a file name `Dockerfile` that sits in the root of your project.  You specify in this file which commands you want to run on top of the base image.

for example, from your use case:

```
FROM centos7.4.1708

COPY <your files> /opt/

CMD ["program.exe" "-arg" "argument"]
```

- `FROM` - defines the base image
- `COPY` - copies files from the folder you run the command from to the image
- `CMD` - runs this command when the container starts

Build with `docker build . -t image-name`

Run with `docker run image-name`